# Delivery Optimization settings won't save

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to download a game from the microsoft store. Download rate is really low so i looked for any issue on internet and learned about the Delivery Optimization settings. I'm trying to set the download rate to unlimited but every time i check the checkbox and leave the setting page, it's back to unchecked :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Default is everything is unchecked and at 100%

Comment: Then the microsoft store is really really slow compared to any other platform i download from =/

Comment: Suggested workaround - https://superuser.com/a/1592658. Replace `BITS` with `DoSvc`.